# Is iron pyrite dangerous to handle?

Tags: safety, minerals

I have a cube of pyrite similar to:

[image]

(Source: Britannica)

Can pyrite turn into sulfuric acid?

Is this dangerous for me to touch, especially if my hands are sweaty?

Comment: No, pyrite is not dangerous to touch. "Can turn into" is an awfully broad term, it does not mean anything, unless you specify the conditions. Table salt can turn into a poisonous gas (if electrolyzed, that is). Water can turn into an explosive gas. So what? Nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ivan. Good point. By touch I just mean to play around - roll it around in my hands etc.

Comment: Yes, I got that. No, not dangerous.

Comment: Also I should probably have been clearer with the conditions you mentioned. By sweaty hands I was referring to the pyrite getting water on it. I heard pyrite on mine sites turns into acid mine drainage when it gets water on it and oxidises. So I was worried the sweat from my hands would turn my pyrite into sulphuric acid.

Comment: OK, if you'd wear it like a jewel in constant contact with your skin for years, then maybe it would be somewhat dangerous *for the stone*.

Comment: Take it for granite, it's OK. Just don't eat it with St. John's bread, or you'll get pyrites of the carob bean.

Comment: Hahah, took me a bit of google ("Showing results for pirates of the carob,
Search instead for pyrites of the carob") for that to joke to click. Also thanks Ivan, I can roll it in my hands to my hearts content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pyrite does not *turn* into sulfuric acid. You can burn it with oxygen to give iron oxide and $\ce{SO2}$.

$\ce{4 FeS2 + 11 O2 -> 2Fe2O3 + 8 SO2}$

$\ce{SO2}$ with water gives sulfurous acid. To really get sulfuric acid, $\ce{SO2}$ needs to be oxidised to $\ce{SO3}$ ([Contact process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_process)), and then reacted with water. Actually with more sulfuric acid to give oleum, which decomposes into two equivalents of sulfuric acid upon dilution with water.

The surface of the pyrite will react very slowly in the acidic conditions in your hand. Very, very slowly. There might be a faint smell of $\ce{H2S}$ recognisable if you handle the pyrite for a while in your sweaty hands.

(Also with water and oxygen from the air, pyrite will slowly react, to finally give sulfuric acid, which will speed up further reaction/degradation. But this typically needs decades of very bad ventilation.)

Comment: Actually the decomposition of pyrite specimens is a well known problem in the mineral collecting community. It isn't dangerous to the collector, but the specimen can be destroyed. See left hand column on page 2 of the NPS pdf https://www.nps.gov/Museum/publications/conserveogram/11-02.pdf

Comment: A nice crystal as shown in the picture above is not likely to be susceptible to decomposition by a bit of humid air, i guess.

Comment: You guess wrong...

Comment: @MaxW right, but on what timescale?

Comment: Evidently if the pyrite specimen is kept in a very dry case then it will last a very long time. In humid climates perhaps just centuries. The problem became known because museum mineral collections date back over several centuries.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This is my pyrite right here. I got it from a jeweler. It is not dangerous to handle. However touching to much could cause it to lose its lust and shine. You could polish it with a polish rag to a tool that could remove rust. Again safe to handle just don't handle it to much

Answer (score 2):

It's not a safety concern.  However you should be aware that it will oxidize slowly when surfaced and exposed.  This can happen in ores (e.g. at gold mines) and is know as "[pyrite rot](http://preparation.paleo.amnh.org/56/pyrite-disease)" in fossil specimens.